# How can I automatically re-size my main form when hiding the sub form?

Tags: forms

I have a main form and a sub form.  I can hide the sub form depending on the value of a field in the main form.  But the main form still displays the space where the sub form would be.  I can drag the bottom of the form to not show the space but can that be done automatically when the sub form is hidden?

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In a macro I set the "visible" value of the sub form to "No" if a field on the main form contains a certain value.  The macro is an event on the "On load" of the main form.  This does hide the sub form but it doesn't close up the space where the sub form would be if it were visible.  I was hoping there might be a simple way of shrinking the depth of the main form when the sub form is not visible.  If not, I can get round it by having 2 versions of the form (one with the sub form and one without) and open the appropriate version of the form depending on the situation